# Why is the destructor called when initializing and resizing a vector of objects?

Tags: c++, vector

Something occurred in my program, and I can't find if it's supposed to happen or not. And if it is, I don't see why..

Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
  public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

A::A(){
  cout << "creating" << endl;
}

A::~A(){
  cout << "deleting" << endl;
}

int main(void){
  vector<vector<A > > vec;

  vec.resize(5);
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    vec[i].resize(5);
  }

  cout << "END" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output :

```
creating
deleting
creating
deleting
creating
deleting
creating
deleting
creating
deleting
END
deleting
deleting
[..more deleting here]
```

I understand why the destructor is called after the "END" message, but before, I don't. I thought that when the vector resize, the constructor of the class is called, but why the destructor?

Comment: You forgot to user-define the copy ctor. If you do (with output) and put an output after each call to resize(), you will see what's happening.

Answer (score 17):

In C++03 `vector<A>::resize()` has a default parameter, with default value `A()`. It's this temporary that's destroyed. The elements of the vectors are copy constructed from it.

This is "fixed" in C++11, where there are two overloads of `resize`. One has a single parameter, and value-initializes any additional elements. The other has two parameters, and copy-initializes each additional element from the value supplied. In C++11 this program has this behavior:

```
creating
creating
creating
<repeated for a total of 25 "creating"s>
creating
creating
creating
END
deleting
deleting
deleting
<repeated for a total of 25 "deleting"s>
deleting
deleting
deleting
```

In C++03, if an instance of `A` is so shockingly expensive to construct that it's worth minimizing the number, then you could shave it from 5 no-args- + 25 copy-constructions down to 1 no-arg- and 25 copy-constructions with something like this:

```
A default_value;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   // same end result as vec[i].resize(5)
   if (vec[i].size() >= 5) {
       vec[i].erase(vec.begin() + 5, vec.end());
   } else while(vec[i].size() < 5) {
       vec[i].push_back(default_value);
   }
}
```

You can probably write it slightly differently, and obviously for your example code you don't need the "if" case. But I don't get many opportunities to say "else while", so I'm taking it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this code behaves totally differently in C++11.

Comment: @Csq: yep, I'm way ahead of you. For values of "way" equal to "barely". I was just checking the standard before posting that bit :-)

Comment: Okay.. so there's no way to fix it without C++11? Thanks :)

Comment: @bames53: "fix" was my word so I suppose I should defend it rather than user1729422. What's wrong is that in C++03, 5 instances of `A` are created that are (in the opinion of the C++11 standard committee) unnecessary.